# How to update the Clang compiler from version 3.1 to version 3.4 in Debian Linux?

Tags: linux, updates, clang++

It is as what the question is saying, I am new on Linux. I need the Clang++ compiler update to version 3.4 for the assignment that I need to do. I simply just typed in Terminal

```
sudo apt-get install clang++
```

this command only install/update my clang++ to version 3.1. And I have no idea how to update it.
I went on the clang++ debian website and see different packages but have no idea how to update it. I copied some command but they don't run on Terminal.
[This is the clang++ site I went to.](http://llvm.org/apt/)
 I tried search online for tutorial or help but there was none that could help me with this issue.
   **I am new to Linux so I will really appreciate it if someone give out a detailed update process.**
   Thank you for your time.

Comment: Sorry, but "how to install program XYZ" is an off-topic Question.  Try "superuser" instead ... or maybe the ubuntu-specific site.

Comment: That site doesn't show you *commands*, but lines to put in your [sources list](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList).

Comment: Answered at your [superuser question](http://superuser.com/a/805888/256629).

Answer (score 0):

You have two good options.  My recommendation is option #2, although it will change a lot of packages on your system.

1. Compile Clang yourself, from sources.  This is fairly easy, it just takes a while because Clang is big, and you may have to install some prerequisites.  This is what I would recommend for Clang developers, or people who want to experiment with the latest and greatest bits of Clang.
2. Update your Debian distribution to [Jessie/testing](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianTesting) or [Sid/unstable](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianUnstable).  This is what I normally recommend for developers who use Debian.  I personally use Sid, but you might prefer the stability of Testing.  I only use Stable for servers.

There's also another option:

- You can "pin" the Clang package from Testing.